# How to get pinyin phonetic in iOS

Tags: ios

```
NSMutableString *pinyin = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"你好"];
if (CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)pinyin, 0, kCFStringTransformMandarinLatin, NO)) {
    NSLog(@"%@", pinyin);
    // nǐ hǎo 
}
if (CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)pinyin, 0, kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics, NO)) {
    NSLog(@"%@", pinyin);
    // ni hao
}
```

From the first if statement above code, I can get the pinyin with the phonetic alphabet.The second if statement, I can get the pinyin which don't carry phonetic alphabet(like ni hao).

But the problem is that I want is phonetic. For example, 'hǎo' represents a third tone in pinyin. And the third tone is what I need.

I use Google to search for a long time, but did not find a correlation method.

Please let me know if any open source or method or other already present for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you :[PinYin4Objc](https://github.com/kimziv/PinYin4Objc).
You can set the format ToneType like this `[format setToneType:ToneTypeWithToneNumber]`, and you'll get the result "ni3 hao3"